# Requests with headers and data

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to convert the following cURL command into a Request in Python.

```
curl -H 'customheader: value' -H 'customheader2: value' --data "Username=user&UserPassword=pass" https://thisismyurl
```

From what I understand, one can GET headers and POST data. So how do I do both like a cURL?

This is what I'm trying:

```
url = 'myurl'
headers = {'customheader': 'value', 'customheader2': 'value'}
data = 'Username=user&UserPassword=pass'

requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Which returns: `HTTPError: HTTP 405: Method Not Allowed`

If I use post: `MissingArgumentError: HTTP 400: Bad Request`

Comment: Do you mean GET with body? Yes, possible. Yes, weird. cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use the `--data` command line argument, `curl` switches to a `POST` request. Do the same in Python:

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

From the [`curl` manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> `-d`, `--data <data>`
>   (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a  user  has filled  in  an  HTML form and presses the submit button. HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a  user  has filled  in  an  HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

You may want to manually set the `Content-Type` header accordingly, *or* use a dictionary for the `data` parameter (and have `requests` encode those to the right format for you; the `Content-Type` header is set for you as well):

```
url = 'myurl'
headers = {'customheader': 'value', 'customheader2': 'value'}
data = {'Username': 'user', 'UserPassword': 'pass'}

requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: Also, [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is the document of requests :)

Comment: As mentioned (Poorly) in my question when I use request.post I receive the 400 Bad Request error. However! When I put the data into a dictionary it worked, so thank-you!

Comment: @JavaNoob: that'll be the `Content-Type` header then. You can make your original version work by setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.